# Cannot cast from and ArrayList to HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, hashmap

I'm having a problem with an ArrayList of a List of HashMaps. I tried to cast it but it is not allowed.  Here is the offending code:

```
List<List<HashMap>> myHashMaps = AsyncMusicHashMap.fillHashMap(path);
HashMap<String, String> artistHashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) myHashMaps.get(0);
HashMap<String, List<String>> albumHashMap = (HashMap<String, List<String>>) myHashMaps.get(1);
HashMap<String, List<String>> songHashMap = (HashMap<String, List<String>>) myHashMaps.get(2);
```

With the following exception message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
    at com.bkane56.mp3.MP3HandlingDAO.addMusicToDatabase(MP3HandlingDAO.java:51)
    at com.bkane56.mp3.MP3Handler.main(MP3Handler.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

The mentioned line 51 in class MP3HandlingDAO is:

```
HashMap<String, String> artistHashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) myHashMaps.get(0);
```

Probably is very simple but I am stuck.

Comment: `myHashMaps ` holds a List that holds Lists of HashMaps. When you get an item from myHashMaps, you get a List of HashMap not a HashMap.

Comment: `myHashMaps.get(0);` returns a `List<HashMap>`. `List != HashMap`

Comment: The fact that your even doing *casts* should be a sign you did something wrong. The point of *generics* is that the compiler knows all the types, so you don't have to cast anything.

Comment: You're misusing `List` and `Map`. You don't create a list of list where index 0 is a list of artists, index 1 is a list of albums, and index 2 is a list of songs. You create an `Artist` class, which has `name` and other properties, including a list of albums, i.e. `List<Album>`. The `Album` class has name, year, ..., and a list of songs, i.e. `List<Song>`. The `Song` class has name, length, ..., and so on. --- Well, it won't support compilation albums like that, but the point is that you don't create a `List` where index number has meaning, or a `Map` to store properties.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels....Missed that..got it now and working fine.

Comment: @ Andreas.....Granted, I don"t really have an effing clue what I am doing (only been programming about 6 months now). But, if I had posted my all of my code you would see that I pulled the metadata from my 60k plus music collection to build the hashmaps as i have and right below that i am populating a database with them. I could figure no other way to make sure the foreign keys would be set up properly.  It was working fine but slowly so I am attempting to do it with multiple threads.

Answer (score -1):

he has an error in your declaration:

```
List<List<HashMap>> myHashMaps = AsyncMusicHashMap.fillHashMap(path);
```

i think this instruction can resolve your problem because if you cast myHashMaps.get(0) into HashMap, your List parameter  maybe a HashMap(String, String). Try again with this declaration :

```
List<HashMap(String, String)> myHashMaps = AsyncMusicHashMap.fillHashMap(path);
```

Thanks